# eclipse close editor automatically

Tags: eclipse, editor

I meet this problem today , when I double click the tab of every editor , or when I choose some text in the editor , eclipse close the editor automatically, anyone who encounter the same problem ? My version of eclipse is as follows:

```
Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819
```

Help me for solving this problem and thanks!

Comment: How *exactly* do you "choose some text in the editor"?

Comment: Using mouse to select any text will close the editor , but when I use keyboard ,it doesn't happen.

Comment: My first instinct would be to check the keyboard mapping but you can't map mouse buttons :-/

Comment: Yes, using left button

Comment: I have checked the close-mapping ,but I found it can't map mouse action.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41478/discussion-between-ohyeahchenzai-and-aaron-digulla)

Comment: I'm out of ideas. What you can try is to start Eclipse with a new workspace. Then make it launch itself in the debugger, so you can debug it.